# Pass map values to JSTL tag that expects map

Tags: jstl, el

I have a custom JSTL tag that expects to receive a list of items.

```
<%@ attribute name="items" required="false" type="java.util.List" %>
```

I have a map at my EL variable

```
${myMap}
```

Is that possible to pass a **map values** to mine JSTL tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frst of all, it's not a custom JSTL tag, but a custom JSP tag). JSTL stands for JSPStandard Tag Librrary, and your custom tag is not part of this standard library.

You need `rtexprvalue="true"` in the declaration of your attribute.

And of course, given that you want to pass a Map, the type should be `java.util.Map` and not `java.util.List`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications! :) The problem is I need to have ability to pass a list too. Is that possible? Maybe I need to populate temp array in JSTL before?

Comment: Then type your attribute as java.lang.Object, and you'll be able to pass whatever you want. Or better, use two different attributes.